# Dynamically change the MLKit version on certain page. Error: failed resolution of: Lcom/google/mlkit/vision/common/internal/Detector

Tags: android, flutter, google-mlkit

my current project containing 1 third party / vendor function which trigger camera to scan documents AND 1 packages "mobile_scanner" (https://pub.dev/packages/mobile_scanner) to scan bar/qr code
my app hit error and crash when trying to open the third party camera to scan document. I found out the problem hit because both(plugin and packages) using different version of MLKit

third party: implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services.mlkit-face-detection:16.1.7'
mobile_scanner: implementation 'com.google.mlkit:barcode-scanning:17.0.3'

the third party app not touching or calling the barcode scanning MLKIT somehow the app will crash.
after did some research, this is what i concluded even though they didn't specified in the docs https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/release-notes#june_02_2021
i try use both mlkit service that release at the same time. e.g. face-detection:16.1.7 and barcode-scanning:16.1.2 will NOT crash... i tested this by remove the packages and put the implementation in project build gradle

i try to use lowest version of the packages however, the lowest version of packages also using MLKit that is higher than the third party app

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It's not guaranteed that a higher version of one ML Kit SDK is compatible with a lower version of another ML Kit SDK. Please try to update both to latest versions. https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/release-notes#latest_versions